# Time propogates with an offset

Tags: windows-server-2008, time-synchronization, w32time

The network is simple,

- Two Domain Controllers
- Servers
- Client Workstations
- Other Devices

The primary DC is configured to synchronize time with NTP servers. The secondary DC and other Servers are configured to synchronize with PDC. Time on the PDC is accurate but Other devices are off by atleast 45 seconds.

**Output of w32tm /query /configuration on DC1**

```
C:\>w32tm /query /configuration
[Configuration]

EventLogFlags: 2 (Local)
AnnounceFlags: 5 (Local)
TimeJumpAuditOffset: 28800 (Local)
MinPollInterval: 6 (Local)
MaxPollInterval: 10 (Local)
MaxNegPhaseCorrection: 3600 (Local)
MaxPosPhaseCorrection: 3600 (Local)
MaxAllowedPhaseOffset: 300 (Local)

FrequencyCorrectRate: 4 (Local)
PollAdjustFactor: 5 (Local)
LargePhaseOffset: 50000000 (Local)
SpikeWatchPeriod: 900 (Local)
LocalClockDispersion: 10 (Local)
HoldPeriod: 5 (Local)
PhaseCorrectRate: 7 (Local)
UpdateInterval: 100 (Local)


[TimeProviders]

NtpClient (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\system32\w32time.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMinutes: 15 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMaxTimes: 7 (Local)
CompatibilityFlags: 2147483648 (Local)
EventLogFlags: 1 (Local)
LargeSampleSkew: 3 (Local)
SpecialPollInterval: 900 (Local)
Type: NTP (Local)
NtpServer: time.nrc.ca,0x1 time.chu.nrc.ca,0x1 (Local)

NtpServer (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\system32\w32time.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 0 (Local)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)

VMICTimeProvider (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\System32\vmictimeprovider.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
```

**Output of w32tm /query /configuration on DC2**

*Note: DC2 is affected by the offset*

```
C:\>w32tm /query /configuration
[Configuration]

EventLogFlags: 2 (Local)
AnnounceFlags: 10 (Local)
TimeJumpAuditOffset: 28800 (Local)
MinPollInterval: 10 (Local)
MaxPollInterval: 15 (Local)
MaxNegPhaseCorrection: 4294967295 (Local)
MaxPosPhaseCorrection: 4294967295 (Local)
MaxAllowedPhaseOffset: 300 (Local)

FrequencyCorrectRate: 4 (Local)
PollAdjustFactor: 5 (Local)
LargePhaseOffset: 50000000 (Local)
SpikeWatchPeriod: 900 (Local)
LocalClockDispersion: 10 (Local)
HoldPeriod: 5 (Local)
PhaseCorrectRate: 1 (Local)
UpdateInterval: 30000 (Local)


[TimeProviders]

NtpClient (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\system32\w32time.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
CrossSiteSyncFlags: 2 (Local)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMinutes: 15 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMaxTimes: 7 (Local)
CompatibilityFlags: 2147483648 (Local)
EventLogFlags: 1 (Local)
LargeSampleSkew: 3 (Local)
SpecialPollInterval: 3600 (Local)
Type: NT5DS (Local)

VMICTimeProvider (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\System32\vmictimeprovider.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
NtpServer (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\system32\w32time.dll (Local)
Enabled: 0 (Local)
InputProvider: 0 (Local)
```

**Output of w32tm /monitor on DC2**

```
C:\>w32tm /monitor
DC1.myorganization.com *** PDC ***[10.0.1.16:123]:
    ICMP: 1ms delay
    NTP: +0.0000000s offset from DC1.myorganization.com
        RefID: time.nrc.ca [132.246.11.227]
        Stratum: 3
DC2.myorganization.com[10.0.1.21:123]:
    ICMP: 0ms delay
    NTP: +52.3940859s offset from DC1.myorganization.com
        RefID: 80.84.77.86.rev.sfr.net [86.77.84.80]
        Stratum: 2

Warning:
Reverse name resolution is best effort. It may not be
correct since RefID field in time packets differs across
NTP implementations and may not be using IP addresses.
```

These are my questions;

- Why is there an offset of 52.394 seconds and where is it set?
- What is the IP address `86.77.84.80`?

Comment: What is the output of `w32tm /query /status /verbose`?

Comment: It turned out to be Time Synchronization in HyperV. Thank yo for your reply :)